# Activerecord method for "as" - Derived Alias

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, activerecord

I am trying to build a SQL query using ActiveRecord methods.  The query has a few joins which require derived tables, like this:

```
(SELECT voteable_id, COUNT(vote) FROM votes WHERE vote = 0 GROUP BY voteable_id) AS example
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to find a method that would allow me to create an alias for my derived table (here: AS example).  My question thus is, is it even possible to build such a query using activerecord methods?

EDIT: just to make it more clear.  I have the following methods to build the select statement.

```
t = Vote # Vote being the table name
t = t.where("vote = 0")
t = t.group("voteable_id")
t.select("voteable_id, COUNT(vote)")
```

but how would I go about adding the "AS" alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the result of #to_sql:

```
t = Vote # Vote being the table name
t = t.where("vote = 0")
t = t.group("voteable_id")
sql = t.select("voteable_id, COUNT(vote)").to_sql
t.connection.find_by_sql("(#{sql}) AS example")
```

The real question is *why* you need to use an alias. Answer that and we'll be better placed to help you.

Comment: the real reason I am using an alias is because this derived table is part of a bigger query which it gets joined onto.  without the alias it does not work as far as i am aware